# How to set cloud foundry target?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, cloud-foundry

I am to trying to deploy an application to Cloud Foundry which is running on my local vagrant machine. I have deployed CF using BOSH lite.

Here are the steps that followed:

1. `vagrant ssh`
2. `sudo apt-get install git wget`
3. spiff installation
4. git clone bosh-lite directory
5. git clone cf-release directory (bundler installation in this folder)
6. `cd bosh-lite`
7. `bin/provision_cf`

From my machine I am trying to set the `cf target`, cf is running on VM.

1. `cf api https://api.bosh-lite.com --skip-ssl-validation`

I am getting the following error:

```
rle0249@rle0249-Latitude-3450:~$ cf api https://api.bosh-lite.com --skip-ssl-validation
Setting api endpoint to https://api.bosh-lite.com...
FAILED
Error performing request: Get https://api.bosh-lite.com-v2-info: read tcp 192.168.152.27:36204->10.244.0.34:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Set it to `cf api https://api.bosh-lite.com --skip-ssl-validation`.  You have a `-` instead of a `//` in your API URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the API URL is `https://api.10.244.0.34.xip.io`, unless you've made changes to the configuration.

Note also that you'll need to have run the [`bin/add-route`](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite/blob/master/bin/add-route) script before trying to do this, otherwise your machine won't be able to route to CF through Vagrant / BOSH Lite.

If these steps don't work, I suspect you may have made an error in your installation. I assume you're attempting to deploy from your local machine, outside Vagrant?

Comment: In more recent versions of bosh-lite, the API URL is `https://api.bosh-lite.com` because `xip.io` is flaky.  It also sounds like they're working from inside the vagrant VM for some reason, so I don't think they need to run `bin/add-route`.

Comment: what i am supposed to do now ....is there any way to fix this error..i have ran the bin/add-route as well after that i am facing this issue..

Comment: i am trying to set the cf api target from my machine where vagrant is installed ...do i need to run the command inside vagrant machine..

Comment: You do not need to run anything inside the vagrant machine.  Even all the git clone commands, spiff, etc. are normally all done outside the vagrant machine.

Comment: Thanks @AmitKumarGupta